# Flask app IIS: Keep getting 404 when routing to other pages

Tags: flask, iis-10, wfastcgi

I need help on how to make routing in my flask app hosted using IIS windows server 2012 possible. The home [starting page] works though also cannot load images but it works. The error I get is 404 whenever I click on links leading to other pages in the application. Is there anyone who can assist and tell me what I am doing wrong?

Error i get is[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the following to the web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" >
    <remove name="UrlRoutingModule"/>    
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but when I add the <remove name="UrlRoutingModule"/>  it produces a 500.19 error that the config file is malformed.

Comment: Can you show me the details of the 500.19 error?